# The type or namespace name 'Http' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#

Previously I used VS 2019 and my code was working fine. Now I am using VS 2022 and the code is showing a compile time error.

I tried

```
using System.Net; 
using System.Net.Http;
```

but this dll available.

I added and removed multiple times. But it's not working and I still get the same error message. The problem started appearing after updating to Visual Studio 2022.

Please help me with this. I am working for the first time on this VS version.

Comment: Nuke your `bin` and `obj` directories, restart VS, and run NuGet package restore.

Comment: I have done . but still have a problem

Comment: What kind of application is this? .NET vs .NET Core? COmmand line vs. Winforms vs. Webforms vs ASP.NET MVC vs. ASP.NET Core ?

Comment: there will also be line number mentions also try it to open in vscode may be that will point out if this error occur from IDE only

Comment: marc_s  i am working  webforms

Comment: Is System.Net.Http found in a new project?

Comment: yes found   shingo

Comment: did you try dotnet restore cmd on console

Comment: no i am not tried. can you tell me how can i do

Comment: You may compare the csproj files. You can also move files to the new project.

Comment: Did you change the version of .Net in the project? Visual Studio is an editor, not a language compiler. It uses .Net to report errors and what not during compilation. To be clear, you go back to VS 2019 and it *currently* builds?